# issues with div in TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm, real-mode

I have a little problem with a div, i need some help with this problem,  I have an application in TASM, I  must find the multiple of 3 in a series of numbers, the problem is when i do a div the program freezes and i have no idea why.

My code is:

```
.model small
.stack 1000h
.data

msj1 db 13,10,'Tirame un numero: ','$'
msj2 db 13,10,'ES MULTIPLO DE 3 : ','$'
msj3 db 13,10,'NO ES MULTIPLO DE 3 : ','$'
var1 db ?
cont db 0

.code
.startup

call limpia
mov ah,09h
lea dx, msj1 ;desplegar numero 1:
int 21h

call leer ;lee primer numero
sub al,30h ;restar 30h para obtener el numero
mov var1,al ;lo guardo en var1
mov ah,09h

mov cl,al
mov cont,1

 ciclo:  
            ;push cont
            mov al ,cont
            mov bl,3
            div bl ;this is where the prog freezes , if you comment this line the prog runs

            cmp ah,'0'          
            je multiplo
            jne nomult   

            multiplo :
                mov ah,09h
                lea dx, msj2 ;desplegar numero 2:
                int 21h

                mov dl,cont ;mover al a dl para imprimir
                add dl,30h ;sumar 30 para obtener caracter
                mov ah,02h ;imprimir caracter
                int 21h
                inc cont

            nomult:
                mov ah,09h
                lea dx, msj3 ;desplegar numero 2:
                int 21h     

                mov dl,cont ;mover al a dl para imprimir
                add dl,30h ;sumar 30 para obtener caracter
                mov ah,02h ;imprimir caracter
                int 21h     
                inc cont    

loop ciclo
.exit

limpia proc near
mov ah,00h
mov al,03h
int 10h
ret
limpia endp

leer proc near
mov ah,01h;leer caracter desde el teclado
int 21h;lee primer caracter
ret
leer endp
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`div bl` is dividing `ax` but you only load `al`. Presumably `ah` has leftover value in it, so the `div` overflows. Try loading `ax` for example by using `movzx ax, cont`.

Also, learn to use a debugger in conjuction with the instruction set reference.

Answer (score 1):

When the dividend is 8 bits, the quotient will be stored in `AL`. Therefore you need to make sure that the quotient will fit in 8 bits, or your program will crash.

You can achieve this by clearing the `AH` register before the division, e.g. using one of the following methods.

```
CBW   ; only if AL is unsigned (00h..7Fh)

; or..

MOV AH,0

; or..

XOR AH,AH
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers , i'm seeing some improvements thanks to your advices